# log4j2 using CsvParameterLayout, how to add timestamp in the cells?

Tags: java, timestamp, log4j2

I am using log4j2's `CsvParameterLayout` to log.

```
logger.info("unzipPhase logging", "Timestamp", "Level",  "RenamedPath","Instruction","Status", "Message", "Layer#", "Thread#");
logger.info("unzipPhase logging...", "????", "info",  newName.getAbsolutePath(),"unzip","success", "Message...", "Layer#",Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Is there any simple and direct way to get `Timestamp`?

Comment: Hello, the answer to your question is `yes`, there are many ways to get timestamp, for example, `System.currentTimeMillis();` `new Date().getTime();`, `Instant.now()`, etc.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, I originally wanted to ask, is there a way, like patternlayout directly quote the timestamp of the logger itself. If not, I will use the method you recommend

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KeyValuePair` option in `JsonLayOut`.

Please choice and use one among of 3 cases.

**CASE 1. Using `KeyValuePair`**

1. add `JsonLayout` in your configuration file. I used `log4j2.xml`.
   The key is `<KeyValuePair key="timestamp" value="$${date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}" />`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
     <Appenders>

        <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
            <Routes pattern="${ctx:logFileName}">
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:logFileName}"
                                 fileName="./logs/${ctx:logFileName}.log"
                                 filePattern="./logs/${ctx:logFileName}.%i.log.gz">
                        <JsonLayout>
                            <KeyValuePair key="timestamp" value="$${date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}" />
                        </JsonLayout>
                        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="512" />
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

2. Run!
3. Check the output.
   The key is `timestamp`.

```
{
  "instant" : {
    "epochSecond" : 1588683107,
    "nanoOfSecond" : 556000000
  },
  "thread" : "main",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "com.study.Stackoverflow",
  "message" : "log printed! - testFile",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
  "threadId" : 1,
  "threadPriority" : 5,
  "timestamp" : "2020-05-05T21:51:47.556+0900"
}
```

Reference : [Property Substitution - date](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution)

**CASE 2. Using `JsonLayOut`**

1. add `JsonLayout` in your configuration file. I used `log4j2.xml`.
   The key is `<JsonLayout includeTimeMillis="true">`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
     <Appenders>

        <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
            <Routes pattern="${ctx:logFileName}">
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:logFileName}"
                                 fileName="./logs/${ctx:logFileName}.log"
                                 filePattern="./logs/${ctx:logFileName}.%i.log.gz">
                        <JsonLayout includeTimeMillis="true">
                        </JsonLayout>
                        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="512" />
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

2. Run!
3. Check the output.
   The key is `timeMillis`.

```
{
  "timeMillis" : 1588688067619,
  "thread" : "main",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "com.edu.test.Stackoverflow",
  "message" : "log printed! - testFile",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
  "threadId" : 1,
  "threadPriority" : 5,
  "test" : "11111"
}

Reference : [JSONLayout - includeTimeMillis](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout)
```

**CASE 3. Using `System Property`**
Sorry, I couldn't make working code. I don't know how could I adopt it in code.

Reference : [System Properties - log4j2.simplelogShowdatetime](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution)